# API or dataset with listings (property for sales) in an area?

Tags: data-request

I would like to make recommendations for properties that a person can afford in a given location. Do we have any API or dataset that can help us here? For MVP a list of properties with their last sale price can be enough.

Comment: Are you asking for a specific country/area or in general?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions:

Zillow has an [api](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm), which can give you price data from postings and estimates of home values in different areas.

[3taps api](https://3taps.com/) allows you to search craigslist data, including real estate listings.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Idealista has an [api](http://developers.idealista.com/access-request), too, in case you are interested in Spain, Italy or Portugal.