# Are there any free real estate properties database out there?

Tags: api, real-estate, database

I'm looking for a nationwide records on properties that have been sold from 2003 to present. Trulia does not have an API anymore and Zillow's is very limited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API or dataset with listings (property for sales) in an area?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/api-or-dataset-with-listings-property-for-sales-in-an-area)